# Convert xyz file to geotiff

Tags: python, gis, geospatial, gdal, geotiff

I have a file with xyz values which I want to convert to a geotiff so I can serve it on the web using a geoserver. The xyz file is essentially a bathymetry with the points (xy) being on a 5x5 grid (but some points are missing as there are no measurements).

Some points:

```
53827.50 437437.50 -12.71
53832.50 437437.50 -12.71
53837.50 437437.50 -12.71
53842.50 437437.50 -12.71
53847.50 437437.50 -12.71
53852.50 437437.50 -12.71
53857.50 437437.50 -12.71
53862.50 437437.50 -12.71
53867.50 437437.50 -12.71
53872.50 437437.50 -12.71
53877.50 437437.50 -12.71
53882.50 437437.50 -12.71
53887.50 437437.50 -12.71
53892.50 437437.50 -12.71
53897.50 437437.50 -12.71
53902.50 437437.50 -12.71
53907.50 437437.50 -12.71
53912.50 437437.50 -12.71
53917.50 437437.50 -12.71
53922.50 437437.50 -12.71
```

I have tried to convert it with gdal:

```
gdal_translate -a_srs EPSG:28992 input.txt output.tif
```

This does give me a file, but the result is a white image with only a few black dots. What I am looking for is an image that shows a darker color (preferably red) for higher values and lighter color (light red to white for example) for the lower values. I would also want to have the missing cells of 5x5 to be transparent.

Is this possible with python or GDAL from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible with GDAL.
Use following command:

```
  gdaldem color-relief output.tif colormap.txt output_colored.tif
```

Color map (colormap.txt) line has following format: height R G B.
Your bathymetric map color map could be like this:

```
0 254 236 237
-100 198 54 38
```

Of course you have to adjust -100 to your minimal value, adjust RGB values if necessary. Also you can add another values if needed.

Interesting example: https://blog.mastermaps.com/2012/06/creating-color-relief-and-slope-shading.html